# fix alignment to have "="s at one column

Tags: vertical-alignment

In my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1763604/prove-that-if-a-b-and-c-are-sets-then-a-b-cup-a-c-a-b-ca/1763840#1763840), The alignment is not good. 
  How can I fix alignment to have "="s at one column?

Thank you.

Comment: You should not even be writing like that, in a black board it might be fine, but in typeset form it is not recommended to add comments on equation etc as it generally looks bad. You can add it as a comment in the align, via `\intertext{via De Morgan}` or write it afterwards.

Comment: while the alignment can be adjusted when using tex, output in `math.stackexchange` is produced by mathjax, and i don't believe that is capable of handling the necessary complications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I propose this solution… but I would advise for something simpler (second solution):

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{makebox} 

\begin{document}

\begin{align*} (
A - B) ∪ (A - C) & = (A ∩ B^\mathrm{c}) ∪ (A ∩ C^\mathrm{c}) \\%
& = A ∩ (B^\mathrm{c} ∪ C^\mathrm{c}) \\%
&\mathrel{\makebox*{$ = $}{$ \underbrace{=}_{\text{De Morgan}}$}}A ∩ (B ∩ C)^\mathrm{c} \\%
&= A - (B ∩ C)
\end{align*}

\begin{align*} (
A - B) ∪ (A - C) & = (A ∩ B^\mathrm{c}) ∪ (A ∩ C^\mathrm{c}) \\%
& = A ∩ (B^\mathrm{c} ∪ C^\mathrm{c}) \\ %
\text{\scriptsize(by De Morgan)} & = A ∩ (B ∩ C)^\mathrm{c} \\%
&= A - (B ∩ C)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You're welcome. Always glad to help!